# Edit Run Configuration Eclipse From Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm sorry if my question seems to be off-topic but I'm new here.

I have to change run configuration eclipse from Java code. I want to run my  app with a run configuration (for example: Maven build) and inside of my app I want to edit the current run configuration from  maven build to Java application just for a moment.

Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Java code'? You can modify a run configuration in an Eclipse plugin installed in the current Eclipse.

Comment: soo...i want to edit run configuration into java application  from java method..(class.java). just for a moment..and then i want to use my first run configuration..that mean maven run ..Thanks for the answer..:)

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on your project and go to `Run As` and select `Run Configurations` option in the menu.
2. A dialog box of Run Configurations will be opened.
3. Select the required configuration from the left hand side list.
4. It will open the selected configuration in edit mode.
5. Make required changes and hit `Run`.

Comment: this is not that i have to find out... i just want to change my run configuration from a java method..not using right click .. :) thanks